# Dropdown cut off by container in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

[image]

Hi Everyone,

I attached the image of my issue and it only is an issue in IE 9. Basically the dropdown is cut off by the outer container. I tried `position: relative;` on the dropdown as well but it make the row expanded by the same height of dropdown.[image] Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: please add more description and code what you tried on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Check the parent div's for `overflow:hidden` and remove it.

Comment: if it was overflow: hidden issue it wouldn't work in Chrome. But it's ok in Chrome. Only IE 9 is an issue.

Comment: It was just a guess since you haven't posted the code yet.

Comment: The reason I didn't post any code is that the code is all in CSS and Jquary table so I had to post massive amount of code. I was seeking your advise for possible solutions and at the end I found a work around and increased the wrapper container height. However it's not an ultimate solution because the dropdown might be longer.